# What's the name of this anti-pattern? Method signature is a liar

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, anti-patterns

What's the name of the antipattern where methods take a generic god-object that has every property you might ever need for a method, rather than explicitly declaring what the method needs?

Eg:

```
public class BaseRequest
{
    User user;
    Car car;
    CustomerRecords customerRecords;
    Folder folder;
    // ... etc for 10 - 20 other unrelated parameters
}

public void doSomething(BaseRequest request)
{
    User user = request.getUser();
    // do stuff with user, ignore all other attributes of request
}
```

Instead of

```
public void doSomething(User user)
{
    // do stuff with user, since it's nice and clear what we want
}
```

Note - I'm not referring to the Single Responsibility Princple which `BaseRequest` violates.  Instead, I'm looking for the name of the antipattern where the method signature is "lying" about its dependencies.

Also, are there any good blog posts that succinctly explain the evilness of this pattern, which I can point someone to?

Comment: Why are you sure that every dumb think in creation has been reified as an 'anti-pattern'?

Comment: @bmargulies this one happens to be :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) violation

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's just an effect of having the [god object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).  The problem *shouldn't* exist when the god object doesn't exist.